# clicking on multiple divs one after the other to trigger another div animation?

Tags: php, jquery, css, animation, click

I've three divs that animate on their clicks. When I finish clicking on these three divs animation on other div should be triggered.
currently what happening is,when i click on any of the three divs, animation on resultant div triggers immidiately. 
how can this be possible with JQuery?

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {

      $(document).on('click', '.prize ,.time ,.judge' , function() {
        $('.contest').hide();
      });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I am not god, Please provide proper html and jquery code?

Comment: can you provide us with a link or jsfiddle? There are a number of ways but without ANY code it's really hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

this is the best I could do without any proper code given!

```
$('div').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).data('clicked')){
        $(this).data('clicked',true);
        if($('#firstDiv').data('clicked') && $('#secondDiv').data('clicked') && $('#thirdDiv').data('clicked')){
            $('#otherDiv').animate({'however you like it'});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: after you click all three divs it should be animated, unless you used it wrong.